# Android Custom button with imageview and textview inside?

Tags: java, android

I'm looking to create a custom button. This button ideally would have an image on the left and a textview on the right. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 22):

### The fastest way

Create clickable View with Button drawable as background that contains ImageView and TextView.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ImageView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:text="Sample text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

### Other way

Create your own class, extend RelativeLayout, set content view as above, add custom methods to set text, image etc. and that's all.
Use your custom layout.

Answer (score 10):

you may to use such code for that task:

```
<Button
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
 android:text="@string/text"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_image"
 android:background="@drawable/login"/> // this is for nice background - *.9.png
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a xml with the Layout you want, xreate a drawable which look like you want the Button to look, add the drawable as background to Linear Layout and inflate the xml to a custom view.

Example drawable:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">     
<item android:state_pressed="true" >         
    <shape>             
        <solid android:color="#f3ae1b" />             
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#bb6008" />             
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />             
        <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />         
    </shape>     
</item>     
<item>         
    <shape>             
        <gradient 
            android:startColor="#f3ae1b" 
            android:endColor="#bb6008" 
            android:angle="270" />             
        <stroke 
            android:width="1dp" 
            android:color="#bb6008" />             
        <corners 
            android:radius="4dp" />             
        <padding 
            android:left="10dp" 
            android:top="10dp" 
            android:right="10dp" 
            android:bottom="10dp" />         
    </shape>     
</item> 
  </selector>
```

Edit: Code to inflate

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
public LinearLayout yourButton;
yourButton = (LinearLayout)  mInflater.inflate(R.xml.yourButton, null);
```

Comment: I alwas use that code, would the two downvoter be so kind and explain?

Comment: I didn't down vote, but imho it's unnecessary complicate for his requirements. Why use a layout inflater and xml layout, if he can just use one button tag and set a drawable to the left, see Anton Derevyanko's reply below.

Comment: thats right, I didn't even know the drawableLeft value, would be very useful in various cases, but somtimes I like the inflating of custom views very well, becous of the ability to implement various functions and behaviours.

Comment: The drawableLeft attribute isn't that useful, it doesn't scale properly, and you don't get much control over it.

Comment: Also, make sure on the LinearLayout to set android:clickable="true" -- this works great when just setting it as a background; though I can't figure out what you're trying to accomplish with the LayoutInflator -- everything seems to work fine without that bit.

Comment: Also, I found that just setting the LinearLayout's "style" attribute's value to "?android:attr/buttonStyle" works as well -- you don't have to do any of that custom XML stuff.

Answer (score 1):

In Xml layout use this drawable layout options and get simple layouts.The following line gives the image at the left side of the text.

`android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write code to do this, use setCompoundDrawables() of the Button class to decide where the drawable should appear relative to text.
Look for the API for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using NoboButton

*Simple and fast way to create android button with icon, radius, background*

Library url  https://github.com/alex31n/NoboButton

Screenshot  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alex31n/NoboButton/master/Assets/button_screenshot.jpg

Comment: Please include at least the gist of your suggestion in your post - (external) links may turn stale.