# How to cut the TextView edges in android

Tags: android, textview, google-maps-android-api-2

[image]

If you observe the above picture there is one white color one `Food Delivery`, how can I achieve this. I am drawing the circle in Activity class.

I used `TextView` but I don't know how to cut the edges to align along with circle. Or else do I need to use image with cutting edges?

Please help me out.

Comment: I think you use image, its better Dear.

Answer (score 1):

what you need is a custom view containing an image with the shape you expect your final view to have and a textview. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5665634/3990512) is so similar to your case, therefore I avoid repeating it.

Hope it helps